# Need Tips for Expanding My Organisation's Guest Network

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan, overflow

I work for a Conference Center and we are rebuilding the network for our guests to use. I am functionally a high school intern with relatively little networking experience but I have so far put in a new router to replace our old one and put new AP's around the building. All the equipment is /24 or Class C (not by choice) and my new concern is that we will have far more than 256 guest devices on this router.

So I have been looking into VLAN thinking that maybe I can branch off half the devices into a different subnet so that I could have 512 devices between 192.168.1.* and 192.168.2.*
I am using a Cisco 4 port Gigabit RVS4000 and so far it seems I can't do that (hopefully I'm wrong).

So then I thought maybe I could reconnect the old, still perfectly functional router as a redundant system on 192.168.2.1 and set that DHCP to grap the X.X.2.* range, but I'm concerned that would either mess up our seamless roaming or not connect properly to the AP's that are still on X.X.1.(2-6) (although I would like to be paid to come in and change their IP's every time we needed to use the overflow system I don't think my boss would appreciate the extra work).

I also think there should be a better way than two whole routers.

So is there anything I'm missing or should I just keep plugging about with parallel routers?

EDIT: Router only supports 255.255.255.* which is horrid https://i.stack.imgur.com/0spDa.png

Comment: Classful networking no longer exists.  Repeat, 'there is no Class C', 'there is no Class C', 'there is no Class C', ...

Comment: For the record, you're not running a Cisco device, you've got a Linksys device. Cisco bought them about 10 years ago and started slapping the word Cisco on them to give them more cred (and sadly seems to have worked). But it's a long, long way from being a proper Cisco device.

Comment: The RVS4000 is just a crappy €100 SOHO device and in no way an acceptable choice for a conference center network that will likely at times have to handle hundreds of users. For this type of network to work reliable, you have to use professional networking equipment (e.g. real Cisco) and spend quite a lot of money for it.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to adjust the subnet mask on the internal interface of your router.  Right now it is probably 255.255.255.0, adjust it to something like 255.255.252.0.  Update the mask on any devices with a static address.

Comment: I wish I could, the router only supports 255.255.255.*

Comment: Are you sure? This is quite difficult to even *believe*...

Comment: If the router truly doesn't support other subnet masks then you should probably be looking for a different router.

Comment: I know, but this is all I got http://i.imgur.com/icXBd.png

Comment: This is positively *scary*.